# Org Mode exclude subtree from agenda views

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'd like to tag or else mark a subtree as on the "backburner" and exclude the subtree (and its children) from all agenda views, e.g. agenda, to do, match list, etc.

Basically this would replicate the functionality of the `:ARCHIVE:` tag, except I already use that tag for archiving, and it appears that `org-archive-tag` does not accept multiple strings.

I've also tried the following:

```
#+TODO: TODO | DONE
#+TODO: WAIT BURN | CANC
```

This allows me to exclude a single subtree, but not its children, so it's not particularly useful for sending a whole project to the backburner.

Any ideas or alternate workflows I might try for putting projects on the backburner?

Comment: Here is a variable that applies to todo items:  `org-agenda-todo-list-sublevels`.  Here is a variable that applies when using the `org-tags-view` function:  `org-tags-match-list-sublevels` -- *Non-nil means list also sublevels of headlines matching a search.
This variable applies to tags/property searches, and also to stuck projects because this search is based on a tags match as well. . . .*  [The default setting is `t`.]  As you may already be aware, there are three main search functions -- `org-agenda-list`, `org-tags-view` and `org-search-view`.

Comment: @lawlist unfortunately this achieves the opposite of what I'm after, i.e. with `org-agenda-todo-list-sublevels nil` marking a subtree as `BURN` will exclude that subtree, but then include all its child `TODO` entries. Ideally I'd like to mark/tag a subtree and exclude it and all child entries (regardless of TODO status).

Comment: Since the question invites ideas/alternate workflows:  My headings match Toodledo and I synchronize my computers (desktop and laptop) and mobile devices: https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo   I use `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "Active(a)" "Next Action(n)" "Canceled(c)" "Hold(h)" "Reference(r)" "Delegated(d)" "Waiting(w)" "Postponed(P)" "Someday(s)" "Planning(p)" "|" "None(N)")))`  I use `Active` for tasks due today.  I use `Reference` for my attendance at special events.  I use `Delegated` for my attendance at meetings, or things like the house-keeper coming over . . . .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding the [`COMMENT` keyword](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html) to any subtree you don't want to see in the agenda:

```
* TODO I will show up in the agenda    
* COMMENT TODO I won't show up in the agenda
```

Use <kbd>C-c ;</kbd> (`org-toggle-comment`) from anywhere inside a subtree to add (or remove) the `COMMENT` keyword.

Note that this works for more complex outlines as well, i.e., if a subtree has the `COMMENT` keyword set, its children will also be excluded from the agenda. There is no need to comment out subtrees whose parents carry the `COMMENT` keyword.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Extra points because `org-comment-string` can be set to e.g. `BACKBURNER`

Comment: Hi, is there a way to apply `COMMENT` to the entire file? I specify directories in my `org-agenda-files` because I don't want to list down all the file manually. However, the downside is that this picks up all the files in the directory and I'd like to exclude just 1 file.

Comment: @kshenoy Some options: 1) place all items in file under a `COMMENT` parent, 2) glob your agenda directory for org files, use something like `seq-filter` to remove the specific files you want to ignore, and set that to your `org-agenda-files`; this works best if you only want to filter a few files.