# viewing Parents only, no Children, in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to use `agenda` to generate a list of currently active projects. An active project (for me) is an entry tagged with `wip` and is not a TODO entry. I would like the list to have only the top-most entry, ignoring all children. Thus, once the search has hit a match, it can skip searching all children.

I am having difficulty because because tags are inherited by children, and therefore, children show up in my search --- how do I prevent this? For example, doing a `match` in `agenda` using `wip+TODO=""` strips out the TODO items (that's good) but parents and all children inheriting the `wip` tag show up.

*Note*: the top-most entry is not necessarily at `LEVEL` 1 or 2. The top-most entry with a `wip` tag could be deeper in the outline structure. I am using `agenda` because I need to search across several org files; otherwise, within a single org file, I would just create a sparse-tree.

Answer (score 2):

I think I arrived at a solution. It seems to work from initial testing.

`(setq org-tags-match-list-sublevels nil)`

Then do `M-x org-tags-view` and use search string `wip+TODO=""`

I found the key insight from @lawlist who responded to a different question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7709/25547).

I will probably write a function to do this so that I change the value of  `org-tags-match-list-sublevels` only when I need to execute this specific search.